# How to make a post on the wall with photo using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have two cases to be handled in javascript :

1) timeline post with image and text

2) timeline post only with text

Case **#2** can be handled using "**/{page-id}/feed**" api and I can list those posts using "**/{page-id}/posts**". I will get the id, message as the result.

But for **#1**, it's not possible to add an image along with the message. Api says that a picture can be added with the **link**. But I don't want any such links in the post.

How is this possible to post with text and image? And how to list the posts created for the above two cases in a single api call ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating

Comment: @CBroe, okay. If I use "/user/photos" for case #1 and "/{page-id}/feed" for case #2, how about getting the list of posts in a single api call (which contains the post uploaded in both cases)?

Comment: They are different kinds of objects, and therefor you need to request them from different endpoints. (In the feed you will at most get to see those meta-posts Facebook creates automatically, like “Foo added a new photo to their album bar”.) But you can do it using one API request, via Field Expansion (see documentation on basic API usage.)

Comment: thanks for your time. I have got the results from /page-id/feed GET method.